# I need a loop in Jquery from 'active' item

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm now in JavaScript and I want to make a loop setting each  `<li>` with class "active" from n° 1 to `<li>` n° 4 and start again to n° 1 EVERY 3 SECONDS.

I have this code until now:

HTML

```
<ul class="collection">
     <li id="first" class="collection-item active">Desplazate hacia la pestaña <strong>HORARIOS</strong>.</li>
     <li id="second"  class="collection-item ">Ingresa tu N° de documento.</li>    
     <li id="third" class="collection-item ">Presiona el botón <strong>INGRESAR</strong>.</li>
     <li id="four" class="collection-item "><strong>LISTO!</strong> Ahora puedes ver los horarios de la semana.</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){


    setInterval(animacion,3000);

    function animacion(){
        $currently_selected = $('li.active')

    // Loop back to first sibling if on the last one. 
        if ($currently_selected.next().length = 0){ 
        $next_selected = $currently_selected.siblings().first()
    } else {
       $next_selected = $currently_selected.next()

       $currently_selected.removeClass('active')
       $next_selected.addClass('active')
    }

    }
});
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

- Use `==` or `===` while testing the `length` as `=` will act as `assignment operator` and it will always be evaluated as `true`
- `else` block should be closed after assignment of `$next_selected` variable

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(animacion, 3000);

  function animacion() {
    $currently_selected = $('li.active');
    if ($currently_selected.next().length == 0) {
      $next_selected = $currently_selected.siblings().first();
    } else {
      $next_selected = $currently_selected.next();
    }
    $currently_selected.removeClass('active');
    $next_selected.addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="collection">
  <li id="first" class="collection-item active">Desplazate hacia la pestaña <strong>HORARIOS</strong>.</li>
  <li id="second" class="collection-item ">Ingresa tu N° de documento.</li>
  <li id="third" class="collection-item ">Presiona el botón <strong>INGRESAR</strong>.</li>
  <li id="four" class="collection-item "><strong>LISTO!</strong> Ahora puedes ver los horarios de la semana.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's  just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Heres one way to do it.

```
setInterval(function(){
var items = $('.collection li');  
items.each(function(ind,val){
     if($(this).hasClass('active')){
          $(this).removeClass('active');
          if(ind !== items.length - 1) {                
              items.eq(ind + 1).addClass('active');
              return false;
          }else{
              items.eq(0).addClass('active');
              return false;
          }
     }
});
},3000);
```